# How to display three dots after description?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I used text-wrap to display text in multiple lines. I want to show three dots when text is greater than one line.

```
<ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="list.STATUS=='ACTIVE'" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
      <div (click)="list.isExpanded = !list.isExpanded" [style.height]="list.isExpanded?'auto':'20px'">
        <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 15px;">{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>
        <hr>
        <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 10px;">{{list.DEADLINE_DT}}</p>
      </div>

    </ion-item>
```

Before Click
[image]

After click
[image]

Comment: use a `Pipe`,  https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: [use css for text-overflow: ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: i used text-overflow: ellipsis but its not work.

Answer (score 0):

**.html**

```
<ion-item text-wrap *ngIf="list.STATUS=='ACTIVE'" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
      <div (click)="list.isExpanded = !list.isExpanded" [style.height]="list.isExpanded?'auto':'20px'">

        <p [class.isCollapsed]="!list.isExpanded">{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>

        <hr>
        <p>{{list.DEADLINE_DT}}</p>
      </div>
</ion-item>
```

**.scss**

```
.isCollapsed{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I used this code but its not show three dots with line.Please tell me how to show dots.

Comment: Can you check in browser with inspect element whether the class 'isCollapsed' is applied when the description is in a collapsed state?